# Laravel Categories

Tags: php, laravel, categories

I'm learning php with laravel and  trying to implement categories and subcategories for multiple on my project.
For Example: I have Books, Mobiles in my project
Books has its own categories and subcategories. Same goes for Mobile.

I have added another table with relation

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
          $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
          $table->unique(array('product_id', 'category_id'));

          // foreign key constraints are optional (but pretty useful, especially with cascade delete
          $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Category Database Schema

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('title')->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('keywords')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

category.php (Model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Category extends Model
{
  use Sluggable;
  /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }
  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $table = 'categories';

   /**
    * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
      'parent_id', 'title', 'description', 'slug'
    ];

    public function parent()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function categoryProduct(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('CategoryProduct');
    }

    public function product(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Am i doing the right way as i didn't find a proper tutorial for this kind of approach. Do i need to create a CategoryProduct.php model and reference

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to create a model for a pivot table. Eloquent has many methods to make working with pivot tables a breeze. In your case you don't need a model.

But sometimes, when you're working with pivot table additional columns a lot it's a good idea to create a model for a pivot table.

Comment: Ok. And do i need to say class Category extends Eloquent

Comment: @SrikanthGopi `Category` class should extend `Model`

Comment: I got it. Thanls @AlexeyMezenin